# how to iterate through a word and group the letters by 2

Tags: java, string

I would like to know how I can  group the letters in a word by 2 in java.

Say for instance I have `ABCDE`, I want it to be `AB,BC,CD,DE`. 
I tried using the `subString()` but it gives me only the **first two letters**.

Comment: Looks like a homework. Post what you tried

Comment: Do as they are **saying**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP's minimum effort.

Comment: When you use `.substring(start, 2);` you are meant to give different values to the `start`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera That's no longer an official close reason. The correct one to use here is the one that starts with "Questions seeking debugging help ...".

Answer (score -2):

This question is pretty simple. You can still use substring(start, end) to extract the pairs.

Suppose the original string is in `String str`,

```
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(str.length());

for (int i = 0, imax = str.length() - 1; i < imax; i++)
    res.add(str.substring(i, i + 2));
```

Comment: Really? If this works Under minimum effort showed by OP. Don't expect to provide full answer. Then you will get `-1` any way.

Comment: OK.. I just wanted to show the structure of the problem. Now the code works.